# jquery attr problem

Tags: jquery

```
function rotateimg(ulid,showid,linkid) { 
        var cur = $("#"+ulid+" li.current");            
        var nxt = cur.next("li");           

        if (nxt.length == 0)
        {
        nxt = $("#"+ulid+" li:first");
        }
        cur.removeClass("current"); 
        nxt.addClass("current");
        var img_value=nxt.attr("id").substring(11);
        var img_title=nxt.attr("title");
        var img_id = nxt.attr("name").substring(17);
        var alink=nxt.attr("rel");
        $("#"+linkid).attr("href",alink);

        $("#"+ulid+" li div").css("background-color", "#000000");
        nxt.find("div").css("background-color", "#333333");
        setimg(img_value,showid,img_title);

    }
```

var lt=setInterval("rotateimg('lnews','show_images_event','lnewslink')", 5000);

in this code. i am getting this error **nxt.attr("id") is undefined**

pls any one help me

Comment: There might be more efficient ways to do what you are doing. If you provided some HTML we might be able to better help.

Comment: <div><a href="news_detail.php" ><img src="2.jpg" /></a><ul id="tnews"><li class="show_news_images_topnews" id="show_image_4182010122753PMAmitabh_2.jpg" name="show_news_images_37733" title="Amitabh" rel="news_detail.php"><h4><a href="news_detail.php">Amitabh</a></h4><div> free <a href="news_detail.php"> More</a><div>
</li>
<li class="show_news_images_topnews" id = "show_image_510201012619PMSingam2.jpg" name="show_news_images_38442" title="Singam: Ready to roar in June" rel="news_detail.php"><h4><a href="news_detail.php">Singam</a></h4><div>Kollywood</a><div></li></ul></div>

Answer (score 1):

You'll get `undefined` if `nxt` has no id.
This is a problem, because you're trying to call `.substring(11)` on it.
Do a null check:

```
var img_value = "";
var nxtId = nxt.attr("id");
if(nxtId)
    img_value = nxtId.substring(11);
```

Comment: thanks for reply.now the error not show but it not worked in chrome browser